# Getting new form input values with event - JQuery

Tags: jquery

I currently have a registration form which when clicked from a link opens up in a jQuery dialog modal box. I have used .delegate when the form is submitted.

The JS

```
$('.regForm').delegate("#submit" , "click" , function(event) {

    event.preventDefault(); 

    var form_data = {
        username: $('#regUsername').val(),
        password: $('#regPassword').val(),
        confirm_password: $('#regConfPass').val(),
        email: $('#regEmail').val(),
        confirm_email: $('#regEmailConf').val()
    };
});
```

The html

```
<div class="regForm">
        <form action="http://adomain.com/register/jsReg" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" >
            <table class="regFormTable">
                <tr>
                    <td>Username</td>
                    <td><input class="regInput borderradius3" type="text" name="username" id="regUsername"/></td>
                </tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" class="button borderradius3" value="Register" id="submit"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

The problem is that when I close and reopen the dialog box the forms input values are the same as the first ones.I think it is looking for the first set of id's which match and then getting the values, I may be wrong. I have looked at trying to get the values using event.target but I'm unsure of how get the values.

Any help on this would be much appreciated :)

Comment: how are you reopening the box with form? what is your page structure?

Comment: Your IDs must be unique.

Comment: The box closes when I click outside the box and then I can click the link to open the box again. How do I set the id's to be unique when it is opening a box which loads the same view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs have to be unique. Your problem sounds like you have multiple elements with the same ID.
Do you create a new regForm, each time you open the dialog? If so: To ensure that your IDs are unique, you could [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) the "regForm" after you got the values or you could reset the form values and reuse the existing "regForm" next time user clicks.

Comment: It creates a new dialog box which inside is loading a view. I tried resetting the form values when the user closes the box but had no luck. I will try and remove the "regForm" and see if that works

Comment: Removing the "regform" when the window is closed worked a treat, thank you :)